How to use global props in NextJS, strategy
Usually, it seems to use the method of handing over props from parents to children,
but it seems to be difficult to manage if there's multiple children.
When I used Vue, I used the method of importing and using it from the Store all over the country,
and I was wondering if there was a similar method or if there was a way that suited React.
Now, I'm handing over props hierarchically.
Is there a strategy to manage props drilling efficiently?
If global props is not recommended, I would also like to know why.

For managing global state in Next.js without prop drilling, you can use the React Context API for shared state across components or a state management library like Zustand or Redux for more complex needs. These methods help avoid prop drilling by providing a centralized state that components can access directly. For server state, consider using React Query or SWR to handle data fetching and caching efficiently.
